vue3 - responsive background image from variable
I'm using Laravel and Vue, in the blade template I'm calling a Vue component which I'm passing some props too, to try and be able to update the background image depending on window width:
Blade Template:
<component 
    bg="{{ asset('/images/desktopBG.webp') }}"
    bgm="{{ asset('/images/mobileBG.webp') }}"
></component>

Component:
import { defineProps, computed } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps([ 'bg', 'bgm' ]);

const responsiveBG = computed(onresize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        console.log('background', props.bgm)
        return props.bgm
    } else {
        console.log('background', props.bg)
        return props.bg
    }
})

<template>
    <section id="container" :style="{backgroundImage: responsiveBG}"><section> 
</template>

The props are pulling through fine which I can see when console logging and it updates on window resizing, but I can't get it to be added a background image never mind change depending on the window width.
Any help would be appreciated? thanks

It's strange setting the onresize handler inside the computed call like you have.

computed with onresize is a problem, this shouldn't be done this way. Use a ref. There are third-party composables for this purpose (vueuse)

Thanks okay I will look at another way of doing the onresize, however even without it it should look at the window size on load and choose which prop value to return, so can you please help with getting the correct prop to work as the background image? Thanks

Try this:
<script setup>
    import { defineProps, computed, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, ref } from 'vue';
    
    const props = defineProps(['bg', 'bgm']);
    
    // Track window width with a reactive ref
    const windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth);
    
    // Function to update window width on resize
    const updateWidth = () => {
        windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth;
    };


    // Computed property for responsive background
    const responsiveBG = computed(() => {
        return windowWidth.value < 768 ? `url(${props.bgm})` : 
        `url(${props.bg})`;
    });
    
    // Add and remove event listeners on mount and before unmount
    onMounted(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
    });
    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
    });
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <section id="container" :style="{ backgroundImage: responsiveBG }">
            <slot></slot>
        </section>
    </template>



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks, I actually ended up figuring it out with something not that far off what you put above, I've also tested your way and it does definitely works so I've marked it as the answer thank you

Since your function is returning an object return {'--bg-color': props.bgm}, it seems that this exact object is being passed as a backgroundImage value. Background-image property cannot consume this value.
Try to return correct css background-image value of type string as per MDN documentation

Apologies I'd left in some code for another method I had tried, I've removed the --bg-color it should be just returning the variable values passed through props, which should just be either /images/desktopBG.webp or /images/mobileBG.webp. these should be usable values for a background-image. So can you please help with that?

I actually figured out the answer myself after a lot of trying and figuring, however since then Asatulla above has provided an answer that wasn't a million miles off what I did and it works so I've marked his solution as the answer.
I just wanted to include my solution too:


import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps([ 'bg', 'bgm' ]);

const backgroundCheck = ref({
        backgroundImage: `url()`
    });

    const updateBackground = () => {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        
        if (windowWidth < 840) {
            backgroundCheck.value = {
                backgroundImage: `url(${props.bgm})`
            }
        } else {
            backgroundCheck.value = {
                backgroundImage: `url(${props.bg})`
            }
        }
    };

    onMounted(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateBackground);
        updateBackground();
    });

    onUnmounted(() => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', updateBackground);
    });

<template>
    <section id="container" :style="backgroundCheck"><section> 
</template>



